# Proof on a generalization of Hensel's lifting lemma

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am reading a proof on the generalization of Hensel's lifting lemma (over p-adic integers), particularly on 1-lipschitz functions. I came across a part with notations which I've never encountered before, hence I got confused.

Here are the important given for that part:

$\bullet M_k \subset \{0,1,2,...,p^k-1\} , k \geq1\\
\bullet h_i \in M_i \\
\bullet \mu \text{ is the set of all possible sequences } h_1, h_2,h_3,...,h_k \text{ where } h_k\in M_k  $

And then the confusing part goes like this:

Since $$\lim_\gets M_k = \mu$$
and since $f$ is a continuous function,

then, $$f(a)= 0, \forall a \in \mu$$

I don't get the symbol with the limit with the left arrow, and how that implies to the conclusion shown.

I would appreciate if someone could make this clearer to me. Thank you!

Comment: It is the standard notation for the *inverse* (or *projective*) limit.

Comment: "$f$ is a continuous function" from which to which topological space?

Comment: Sorry, from the set of p adic integers to itself